# Using regularisation regression techniques over linear regression

Tags: regression, regularization

I'm sure similar questions have probably been asked before, so apologies.

I currently have a linear regression model where I have 4 predictor variables. I have purposefully chosen these variables, out of a set of 25, as I am trying to understand these 4 predictor variables effect on the dependent variable.

My dataset do not have any problems with the number of observations, as they are much greater than the number of predictors, and I don't have multicollinearity as I have used a variance inflation factor to check (all values under 5). As I don't have the above issues, and I don't require feature selection, are there any benefits of using regularisation (lasso, ridge, elastic) over the linear regression technique?

The only benefit I could see would be that of avoiding over fitting?

Comment: A issue with regularization for what appears to be your goal is that you bias the coefficient estimates, even squashing some to zero in LASSO. You think that all of these variables influence the response variable. What would you conclude from a LASSO coefficient estimate that is zero? (Btw regularized linear models are still linear models, just not estimated via OLS.)

Answer (score 0):

Ridge regression makes perfect sense if you know that the error structure is a function of the size of the X variable, in which case, it simply reduces weight on observations which could be potentially more noisy.

On the question: "are there any benefits of using regularisation (lasso, ridge, elastic) over the linear regression technique?", with respect to, at least, Ridge Regression, I would expect better coefficients  (as Least-Squares is not particularly robust in the presence of outliers) and corresponding prediction error estimates more likely accurate also (as you have a better handle on the error structure).

You can construct a theoretical regression model and simulate by sampling from the known error structure and compare results of a regularization approach, over repeated simulations, to a more simple Least-Squares.

Comment: Could you explain how ridge regression helps with the kind of heteroscedasticity you describe at the outset?  Since Ridge Regression is (or can be) computed using OLS, how is it any better than OLS at dealing with outliers?

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I understand it, confidence intervals are generally not used for regularisation techniques? Is this not an advantage for linear regression models, where a confidence interval can be built, and thus be able to provide more certainty?